# How do I install the drivers for an ATI Radeon 9100IGP Integrated Motherboard Graphic Card?

Tags: 11.04, drivers, ati

I have fresh install the ubuntu 11.04 but still unlucky to install appropriate driver for my ATI Radeon 9100 IGP (built-in graphic card on Asus Motherboard), because of this UINTY is not working on my system. System switch me to classic mode.

I have tried many method but no success.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this trouble and ended up removing the fglrx driver and using the open source driver. However it was not just as easy as uninstalling the fglrx file.

Here is how to do it easily and correctly. It will clean pretty much all of the fglrx info out of your pc and reinstall the open source drivers for you

Open a terminal and type

```
sudo /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
```

this may or may not be on your pc

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx
```

This as you will see, get rid of pretty much all fglrx material on your machine

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

This will if you have installed it prior to installing 11.04 remove older open source drivers

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
```

Installs the open source files

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
```

as does this

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Sorts it all out on your xserver which is currently blocking you getting into Unity

If you want to be able to reinstall the fglrx drivers at a later point (I have done before) you will need to reinstall the thing which prompted you to install them last time which is done by:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-modaliases
```

Now you will need to reboot and you should be back with the option to log into Unity again

Personally on my desktop I have now stuck with the open source drivers as I am always having issues with fglrx.

Hope that works

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try to use the open radeon or ati drivers from AMD: http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xserver-xorg-video-radeon.