# Ubuntu 11.04 + Radeon 4850 = performance problems and graphic problems

Tags: 11.04, xorg, graphics, ati, performance

I did not install Ubuntu 11.04 on the first day because i tought: okey maybe there are some bugs, i give them some days so they can fix them. But now i got it with the hope the most anoying bugs are gone. But they are not. Not for me with my ati card.

Im got the newest ati catalyst 11.4 - but still there are a lot of performance problems. The window is moving very very slow. And its bucking hard. I dont have fun with compiz :( But even if I deactivate every effects, there are still the performance and bucking problems. When will ubuntu fix these problems? Are there some solutions? The problem is the new xorg right? Why are they putting a new xorg without testing it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

They slowness is caused by the default Compiz settings.

You need to disable the `Sync to VBlank` option in the OpenGL plugin and you might also need to disable the `Detect Refresh Rate` option in the Composite plugin.
[image]

[image]

Comment: lol, I answered it just 24secs late

Comment: hej thank you for the screens. Not its much better!

Comment: ps: why are these setting not standard after the installation?

Comment: I have the `Detect Refresh Rate` option checked and got no issues.

Comment: It seems to be a hit or miss. I have two laptops with an ATI graphics card. Both are 5650m's, but one of them needs the `Detect Refresh Rate` option off. It's pretty weird.

Answer (score 0):

Go to CCSM (Compiz settings manager) > Open GL Plugin and just uncheck the vsync option
[image]
P.S. - I use the same card ATI HD 4850.

Comment: Hey man.. If you really wants to help people, check before posting. Checkout Chen's suggestion. He has already mentioned it.. You are just wasting the space.

Comment: its okey, thank you Ashfame. You just answered some secs later. Dont blame him Abhijeet...

Comment: @Liss thanks! @abhijeet if you consider my answer as wasting space, this is not your land, so don't bother. Liss has already given the response. 2 advice, 1:read comments 2:check the timestamp (hover over it)

Answer (score 0):

I got fed up with fglrx and got rid of it all together as I could not get it working right.

If you need to do that I did a post earlier today here

[Post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41469/ubuntu-11-04-ati-radeon-9100igp-integrated-motherboard-graphic-card/41496#41496)

Comment: Hi andybleaden. I have seen performance issue with the open source drivers. My laptop fans ran at full speed and palm rest got hot with the open source driver. Are you facing any issue with the open source driver. Bcuz I am also thinking to check this option.

Comment: No it is much easier with the open source driver

Comment: @Abhijeet @andybleaden It depends from versions to versions. Sorta race, anyone can be in lead :)